# Idling in Team Fortress 2

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

After the recent class update, I've been trying to increase my play time from 2 to 3 hours per week to 2 to 3 per night in order to receive additional weapon drops. Yet this doesn't seem to be enough to find the weapons that I'm after. My question is:

- What are the latest methods for idling in Team Fortress 2?
- Does Valve still actively punish idlers, and if so, how do I avoid this?

Comment: I think this is a form of cheating and would almost say it goes against Valve's TOS, I just need a new close reason - cheating!

Comment: See the meta post: [How do we stand on cheats, in particularly for multiplayer games?](//meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/489/) for this continued discussion.

Comment: I wish that this wasn't the question that was tied to that meta discussion.  I don't believe this is actually "cheating".  Valve, to my knowledge, has never made a statement condemning legitimate idling.

Comment: Didn't really intend for that to happen, it was just discussed here and on chat and it's the first example on here.
Also, yes, the Announcer (on the blog) has condemned idling (there's no form of legitimate idling) even if you don't use software. They've never followed up on bans so far though.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Valve has said they are fine with people idling as long as they don't use any external programs to "fake it".   That is, as long as it's a regular game client just sitting in an idle server, they don't care.   They did recently change the item system to have a weekly drop limit, so that idling doesn't provide nearly the same benefit as it used to.  Personally, I think that unless you just HAVE to have more hats, there's really no need to idle, you can just do achievements, then use the **very inexpensive** crafting recipes to make the ones that don't come from achievements.

Comment: But, since this question does actually mention "how do I avoid getting punished", it seems to indicate that the asker is trying to get away with something that they perceive to be against the rules, which I think is not something that we should support here.  If it just said "what is idling and how do I do it?", he'd be in the clear (in my opinion), since Valve allows "regular" idling.

Comment: While the arguments sound convincing, I still think that idling or camping ruins the game for others and I don't think we should be a resource of helping people 'actively' ruining other people's experience

Comment: This is just the kind of debate I was looking to spur with my question, good to see there will be an active meta community tied to gaming

Comment: @IvoFlipse - I tend to judge multiplayer cheats based on one simple rule - If it's "hacks for everyone", it's fine (think low gravity servers, extreme speed etc) If it's "hacks for me" I.e. aimbotting, invincibility, wall hacks, etc then it is **not** ok. So where does idling sit? **Anyone** can join an idle server, so it's 'hacks for everyone'. If you choose not to join idle servers, that's your choice. There is no real benefit gained in-game from joining idle servers, so noone is put at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will not be punished for joining a server running "achievement_idle" and leaving your computer on.

However, the marginal gain idling provides means that it's not a very effective way of getting items, especially if running your computer for that long means overheating.

Valve never "punished" idlers, only those who used the external program developed by Drunken_f00l to trick the steam servers into thinking they were in the game, connected to the server, when in fact, they were only connected to the server, outside the game.

For what it's worth, I believe Valve stated that ~1 hour a night was enough to get all your weekly drops.

Comment: nice answer

Comment: Who runs a machine that will overheat just by running for a long time (3D or not)? You should never generate more heat than you can consistently cool.

Comment: My PC doesn't really generate that much heat running TF2, even for elongated periods.

Answer (score 1):

As Raven Dreamer said:

- look for servers with maps containing "idle";
- there is no punishment for idling (currently).

But I would like to complement on what you are trying to do.

The official Wiki states (https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) :

> Players are guaranteed to find items at regular intervals of 30 to 70  minutes, with an average interval of 50 minutes.

Also:

> The system has a cap on the amount of playtime in which drops can occur. This cap has been estimated to be 10 hours each week. Playing beyond the cap **will not yield additional items**.

So, your calculations should be: **10 items** per week, **5 to 10 hours** of gameplay.